# Generating SQL queries safely in C#

Tags: c#, sql

What's the safest way of generating SQL queries in C#, including cleansing user input so it's safe from injection? I'm looking to use a simple solution that doesn't need external libraries.

Comment: some 1 file "external libraries" could make that very simple, like Dapper or PetaPoco

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use Sql Parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.80).aspx

Here's an example in C#

```
SqlCommand tCommand = new SqlCommand();
tCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString");
tCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE players SET name = @name, score = @score, active = @active WHERE jerseyNum = @jerseyNum";

tCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Smith, Steve");
tCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@score", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = "42");
tCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@active", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit).Value = true);
tCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@jerseyNum", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = "99");

tCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: SQL Parameters are an excellent way to start. If the app starts to grow and needs to make lots of SQL calls, it's probably time to look at LINQ or an ORM of some kind.

Comment: I approve (and personaly use a lot LINQ-to-SQL), but I don't really consider it a simple solution (you have to understand the DataContext philosophy to avoid some mistakes), but like I said in the comments, there some tiny helpers out there to build parametrized queries that I would use instead of using directly the SqlClient classes.

Comment: No it isn't. It's just in plain sight, as opposed to hidden under a load of auto generated code so you don't have to bother learning how it works.

Comment: Why need to write so much code when you can do without writing the code.

Comment: @Tony then why bother even writing the code in c#.. it would be better to write in c .. everyone should utilize the features of the language.. Increases productivity..

Comment: Is it possible to get out from the SqlCommand the string with the parameter place-holders replaced with their values, or am I missing the point of Parametrized Queries?

Comment: @dilberted he means it's not old school because the tools you use actually use them under the hood, it's the basics, there's no new way of doing that

Comment: It's only an increase in productivity, if you understand the why of it. Otherwise it's close your eyes, cross your fingers, say the magic words and maybe your chosen deity will smile upon you. Always operate at three levels of abstraction, one either side of the implementation...

Comment: @IAmAl. It's more than a simple replace of a parameter with a value. For instance it knows name is a String and that Sql expects Fred to be wrapped in string delimters, which as usually single quotes.

Comment: @Tony Good point. Though in my case I'm not interacting with a 'SQL server' rather a proprietary application that uses SQL-like language for fetching data, as far as I know, I can't use SQLConnection to issue the query. Not ideal, I know. It's more restrictive that standard SQL, so on the plus side it might be harder to exploit, but I think one should still stick with best practices.

Comment: @Guillaume86 Is LINQ compatible with MySQL? I know.. 8 years later.

Comment: @LV98 you should probably look into EF Core or Linq to DB nowadays, both can do LINQ to MySql AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

In essence don't do this

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(MyConnection);
command.CommandText = "Select * From MyTable Where MyColumn = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
...
```

do

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(MyConnection);
command.CommandText = "Select * From MyTable Where MyColumn = @MyValue";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MyValue",TextBox1.Text);
...
```

Basically never build your sql command directly from user input.

If you use an ORM, such as EntityFrameworks / POCO all queries are done in the latter form.

Answer (score 2):

The first rule of thumb is to make sure you use parameterized queries/commands.  Basically don't dynamically build a sql string that includes something that the user has input into the page.

If you use on ORM (EF, L2S, Nhib), this is typically handled in most cases because most all of them run parameterized queries.

Comment: Never go down the road of nhib too much configuration to be done.

Comment: @Dilberted: I use NHib a lot.  It is a little hard to get started, but it really pays off over the life of a big app.  It's a better product than EF/L2S for more complex projects.

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize your queries.

In case if you build some TSQL which builds some other dynamic TSQL - [then use some described technique](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

What does "parametrizing means?

See, not use something like this:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from mytable where id = "+someVariable;
```

use this:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from mytable where id = @id";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", someVariable);
```

Comment: What does this mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Parametrized Queries.

Simple Example.

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = @Param1";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", param1Value);
    return command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

More Detailed Example.

```
protected void btnGoodAddShipper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connStr = c
      "Server=(local);Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI";

   // this is good because all input becomes a
   // parameter and not part of the SQL statement
   string cmdStr =
      "insert into Shippers (CompanyName, Phone) values (" +
      "@CompanyName, @Phone)";

   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
         {
             // add parameters
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue
                ("@CompanyName", txtCompanyName.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);

             conn.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`DBML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx) and [`LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746) to handle it for you. Many people have worked on those to ensure those issues are well mitigated.

And if not than at least parametrize your queries.

Answer (score 0):

A proper name for DBML is linq2sql or an advanced version is called entity framework. These technologies are provided by Microsoft and well integrated with visual studio. Does not require additional libraries.

Pretty stable products..

Comment: The simplest solution is linq2sql.. No SQL queries to be written

Comment: Simpler? Like this you mean.  from usr in dc.Users join ug in dc.UserGroups on usr.UserID equals ug.UserID join gr in dc.Group on ug.GroupID equals gr.PkID select new { usr, gr }