# can i use AND in update query?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio, sql-update

is this syntax wrong? is it possible that I can't use

> where... and...

```
string str = "UPDATE meetings SET caseNum='" + mt.caseNum + "' ,place='" + mt.place + "' ,MeetingDate='"
                + mt.MeetingDate + "' ,betMishpat='" + mt.betMishpat + "', time='"+mt.time+"' ,description='"+mt.description+"' , " +
                "client='"+mt.client+"' WHERE caseNum='"+mt.caseNum+"' and time='"+mt.time+"' and place ='"+mt.place+"' ";
```

when ever i try to update i get the message that there is a syntax error

Comment: Is the syntax "wrong"?  Well, in a sense . . . you are sticking literal values into a query string rather than using parameters.  In most context, that is quite wrong.

Comment: So, how can I update a query with multiple "where" conditions without parameters?

Comment: The update query string you're building this way is prone to sql injection attacks so it's in that sense that it's wrong. You should use something like `SqlCommand` to build your queries, like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433148/generating-sql-queries-safely-in-c-sharp

Comment: Could you include the actual message? Do you get the error at compile time, or at run time? You should read up on _SQL Injection_ and the story of _Little Bobby Tables_ (https://bobby-tables.com). Also consider getting your query working in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).before using it in a C#  program